# Safe and portable way to write a file in C

Tags: c

I've read that fopen() is deprecated, and fopen_s() is recommended in its place.  But there are many posts outlining the problems with fopen_s() in Linux.  Several tutorials just avoid mentioning that issue, and show how to use both functions.

With that in mind, how should I change this basic function to operate in a manner that is safe and portable?

```
int writeFile( char *fileName, char *textToWrite )
{
    FILE *filePointer;

    filePointer = fopen( fileName, "w" );
    if( filePointer == NULL )
    {
        printf( "Unable to open '%s'.\n", fileName );
        return 0;
    }

    fputs( textToWrite, filePointer );
    fclose( filePointer );

    return 1;
}
```

Since fopen_s has sketchy adoption in Linux, I would like to avoid it if possible.

Comment: Here is a good general reference for C and C++ https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community. We only review code that is working as expected, there are other sites that will answer `How to` questions. We will be happy to review the code in order to help you improve your coding skills once the code is implemented the way you want. Please read [Where can I get help?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @pacmaninbw The code works as expected.  I am asking for a code review to improve it, which made me think this would be a better location than S/O.  I've read the CPPReference page for fopen, and I've read numerous S/O posts about the caveats of fopen_s, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: While the code works as written, you are asking how to alter it to make it work in a different way, that is beyond the scope of Code Review. No stack exchange site that I know of will write your code for you. On code review we only review code written by you from a working project. This question is basically too theoretical which makes it off-topic. Please note the cppreference link I provided shows how to ifdef the code and that should be a good start.

Comment: Note for those finding this in the close vote queue my reason for closing is Missing Review Context.

Comment: @Adam Howell, The C spec has not depreciated `fopen()`.  What is the source of "read that fopen() is deprecated"?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica CLion and Visual Studio 2019 show it as deprecated: https://i.imgur.com/Dao1MtO.png  Following that link takes me to stdio.h in the Windows 10 kit 10.0.18362.0, so maybe it's just a MS thing.

Comment: @AdamHowell When various sources disagree about C, which source should we prefer?  [C spec](https://stackoverflow.com/q/81656/2410359) or Visual Studio 2019.  Be wary of [EEE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embrace,_extend,_and_extinguish) wherever it comes from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- The C spec has not deprecated `fopen()`.
- Use `const` for referenced data when possible.  It conveys code's intent and allows for greater use.
- Check return value of I/O functions.
- Error messages better sent on `stderr`.
- Define and initialize together as able.
- Sometimes code should return quickly like on `fopen()` failure and other times, still need to proceed like to call `fclose()` after `fputs()` failure.
- Consider changing the return value as 0 for success and use various non-zero values to indicate the reason for the error.  (Not done below.).  Consider named or enumerated return values rather than 0, 1.
- Good use of sentinels, `'` in this case, when printing the file name.  IMO, all strings that may contribute to an error deserve sentinels to highlight their beginning and end.  Beginning or end might include hard to perceive white-space.
- As a general rule, You may want to print `errno` on error.  Research `perror()`, `strerror()`.  Also review  [file name, line number and function name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8884335/2410359) for more informative output.
- Consider documenting in code, at least, the overall function goal.

---

```
// Write the string to the file.
// Return 1 on success, otherwise 0.
int writeFile(const char *fileName, const char *textToWrite) {
  int retval = 1;  // Success

  FILE *filePointer = fopen(fileName, "w");
  if (filePointer == NULL) {
    fprintf( stderr, "Unable to open '%s'.\n", fileName);
    return 0;
  }

  if (fputs(textToWrite, filePointer) == EOF) {
    fprintf( stderr, "Unable to write '%s'.\n", fileName);
    retval = 0;
  }

  if (fclose(filePointer)) {
    fprintf( stderr, "Unable to close '%s'.\n", fileName);
    retval = 0;
  }

  return retval;
}
```

Comment: Adam Howell, It is reasonable to consider how we could test for error detection of `fputs()` and `fclose()` errors as they are rare.  There is a school of thought that says if one can not test the error detection, than drop the error detection.  I tend to agree, yet I see it is possible to test the latter 2 errors with some convoluted code like trying to write a huge long string and exceeding file space.